# What do these trigger errors mean

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers

Hey Guys thanks for the help earlier.  I have now ran into a new problem.  A few steps later in my homework I needed to add an additional part to this trigger.  The trigger needs to subtract one from the number of copies.  When the number of copies hits 0 it should display unavailable.  I have been trying for the last few hours to figure it out and this is what I came up with.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

```
CREATE or REPLACE Trigger Unavailable_Rule
 BEFORE INSERT ON Transaction
 FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN


IF :new.Date_Rented_Out  is not null AND :new.Date_Returned is NULL AND Num_Copies=1 
 THEN 
   UPDATE Video
   set Num_Copies = Num_Copies - 1,
    Status = 'Unavailable'
   where Vid_Num = :new.Vid_Num;

ELSE

 Num_Copies = Num_Copies - 1;
 End IF;
 END;
/
show errors;

6/4  PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored  
7/15  PL/SQL: ORA-00971: missing SET keyword  
13/13  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the f ollowing: := . ( @ % ;  
14/2  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `update` statement is misformed.  Instead of:

```
UPDATE Video
   Num_Copies = Num_Copies -1
   set Status = 'Unavailable'
where Vid_Num = :new.Vid_Num;
```

Assign `Num_Copies` in a `set`:

```
UPDATE Video
   set Num_Copies = Num_Copies - 1,
       Status = 'Unavailable'
   where Vid_Num = :new.Vid_Num;
```

EDIT:

Your `if` statement can be replaced with:

```
UPDATE Video
    set Num_Copies = Num_Copies - 1,
        Status = (case when :new.Date_Rented_Out  is not null AND :new.Date_Returned is NULL AND Num_Copies = 1 then 'Unavailable'
                       else status
                  end)
    where Vid_Num = :new.Vid_Num;
```

Comment: Thank you that narrowed down the errors to just these two: 13/13  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the f ollowing: := . ( @ % ;  
14/2  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END"

Comment: There is something also wrong with the else: 'Num_Copies = Num_Copies -1;' Do you need the rest of an update stmt here?  Update Video set Num_Copies= Num_Copies-1 where Vid_Num = :new.Vid_Num;

Comment: 9/3  PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored  
11/3  PL/SQL: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or co lumn specification  
This is what I got

Comment: @BS123 . . . Yes, you need an update statement there.